# Angular dynamic form ngfor multi submit?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, dynamic-forms

I am making a simple quality assessment form with backend mvc api, frontendi angular. In this form I draw the questions api and list them in a table. Next to each question, I put a select / options operator. When I finally want to sumbit, I will collect the answers given to all questions and send them to the api. Select / Options operators come with ngFor. How do I get the value values ​​from these select / option operators. Can you help me ?

Angular
-Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FromElement } from '../Models/FromElement';
import { EndCall } from '../Models/EndCall';
import { CalculateForm } from '../Models/CalculateForm';
import { User } from '../Models/User';
import { FormElementServicesService } from '../services/formElementServices.service';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-KaliteForm',
  templateUrl: './KaliteForm.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./KaliteForm.component.css'],
  providers: [FormElementServicesService]
})
export class KaliteFormComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private formElement: FormElementServicesService) {}
  formValue:FormGroup;
  cagriDegerlendirmesi: FromElement[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formElement.getFormElement().subscribe(data => {
      this.cagriDegerlendirmesi = data;
    });
  }
  selectedOption: string;
  options = [
    { name: 'Evet (20 Puan)', value: 20 },
    { name: 'Kararsız (10 Puan)', value: 10 },
    { name: 'Hayır (0 Puan)', value: 0 }
  ];

  gonder(){
    console.log(this.formValue.value)
  }
}
```

html:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr class="table-light">
      <th scope="col">Kalite Değerlendirme Değerleri</th>
      <th scope="col">Notlandırma</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="table-light" *ngFor="let item of cagriDegerlendirmesi">
      <td>{{ item.fromItem }}</td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group-sm">
          <select class="custom-select" id="{{item.id}}">
            <option class="text-justify" *ngFor="let o of options">
              {{o.name}}
           </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Block level button</button>
```

Comment: Why you are using plain select, you can use [mat-select](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) with you can easily grab the selected value.

Comment: It doesn't matter, you want to get the values when you are submitting form, to do that best way is to use form controls

Comment: I don't know how to do this through a dynamic form.

Comment: [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-mat-select-dynamic-data-binding-in-angular?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.html) is one example how you can do that.